# O que fazer com a tag cores?

Tags: debate, tags

Vi hoje uma pergunta com a tag [cores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cores) e achei essa tag sem muito sentido. Ao olhar a página da tag temos outras perguntas com essa tag e não existe uma wiki para a mesma.

O que podemos fazer com essa tag? Eu votaria em eliminá-la pois a presença dessa tag não influencia nas perguntas onde ela existe.

Comment: Eu acho que nesta pergunta ela faz sentido http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19363/3635, só não acho ela uma tag util ou de grande valor pras perguntas e nas outras perguntas ela realmente não tem muito sentido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento para mim essa pergunta que você linkou que não faz sentido nenhum, rs

Comment: Elas são criadas porque as pessoas acham que as *tags* devem reproduzir a descrição da pergunta quando elas são, obviamente (?!?!), apenas marcadores, agrupadores. "Vou lá ver tudo o que estão perguntando sobre cores". Isto faz sentido? Faz se for usada junto com outras *tags*?  Ajuda achar perguntas? Nem vou entrar no mérito se ela é mal usada, que é outro problema. Eu matei um *tag* que era ótima para ajudar marcar uma pergunta minha, mas ela era usada de forma errada em todas as outras perguntas, achei que o malefício era maior que o benefício, matei-a.

Comment: Qual @bigown? Só por curiosidade...

Comment: mensagem-de-erro

Comment: A pergunta não faz sentido ou a tag? Ok deve ser a tag rs. Então pra mim ele perguntou a diferença das "cores reais" pras "cores no computador". Como eu disse nesta pergunta faz algum sentido, no entanto nas demais não. Entendi o comentário do bigown, talvez seja este o caminho, a tag é raramente usada corretamente, talvez isto tenha que ser o ponto chave aqui (se entendi o que ele disse).

Comment: Eu acho que o argumento sobre o papel das tags, como agrupadores, faz sentido, e também entendo que dificilmente alguém vai querer ver todas as tags sobre "cores". Ao mesmo tempo, há diversas perguntas que podem ser feitas sobre manipulação de cores em computação, de teoria à prática, e algumas delas teriam muita dificuldade em ter mais de 1 tag. Não é bom uma pergunta ter muitas tags. Mas também não é bom ter apenas uma. Uma pergunta só com `python` é tão mal categorizada quanto uma com `python` `django` `django-rest-framework` `url` `rest` `decorators` `middleware` `http` `api`

Comment: Eu li meu comentário acima e percebi que ele é meio ambíguo, pra deixar claro: Eu acho que a tag `cores` não é perfeita, mas ela tem diversas aplicações práticas se for definida direito no wiki e acho que devia ser mantida